# Cribbage scoring for a run

Tags: cribbage

player 1-card 5, player 2-card 7, player 3-card 6 so he gets points for a run of 3, Player 4-card 7 states when he plays a 7 that he breaks the run so player 5 who follows him plays a 5 doesn’t get any points for his run of 5,7,6.

Please advise if this is correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If the three most recent cards form a run (with the total still at or below 31), the player who played the last card gets one point per card in the run.  Any combination of 5-6-7 as the most recent three will do this, regardless what any player might have said about "breaking the run."